# Tomcat Server SSL with multiple domain or sub-domain

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate

I have a Java-Web application running on Tomcat Server with a public IP address `(103.94.xxx.xxx:80)`.
I have some domain/sub-domain that are pointing to my said server with an "A Record" Configaration.
Like these.

1. http://103.94.xxx.xxx/
2. http://bell.abc.com/
3. http://domain1.com/
4. http://domain2.com/
5. http://domain3.ac/
   and more....

Serial 2, 3, 4, 5 .. are pointing to Serial 1.

Question 1 : Can I secure all of these domain/sub-domain along with `103.94.xxx.xxx/Tomcat` by one SSL certificate.
Question 2 : If possible then which certificate is best with low cost.